# What happens when I become infected and what should I do to cure it?

Tags: die2nite

I just started playing Die2Nite, and I have become Infected. I'm out in the desert, and I didn't realize that eating a Meaty Bone had a chance to infect me.

I have no idea how infection in Die2Nite works, so I don't know if I have a chance to infect other members of the town by being in contact with them in the desert or back in town.  Will the infection stay localized to me, or is there a chance to accidentally decimate my town?

What should I do or not do in order to:

- get cured
- not damage the survivability of my town?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're infected, you have a 50% chance of dying overnight, every night. You will *not*, however, infect fellow citizens. The infection stays local to you and you're not going to accidentally decimate your town. The worst that can happen is you die overnight and they either have to water your body down or drag it out into the wasteland.

Do not sacrifice yourself out of fear of this; I've managed to survive two nights in a row in spite of being infected and I can confirm you're more valuable to your town if you manage to stay alive.

There's a drug called the **Paracetoid 7g** which will cure your infection; in order to get it you're going to have to mix pharmaceutical products together and hope you're lucky.

As a side note, if you get infected via wound, it's not enough just to take the drug; you need to **bandage** the wound or the infection will return the next day.